# list of items containing more than one variable in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-2.x

I want to create a list of items where each item may have more than one variable. I read about dict, but there its just two variables. Then I thought of class. However I am not sure how to implement class object inside a list. I would also like to store the data in a db. Can you give me an explanation of how to implement this logic in the code?

Comment: What's wrong with a list of lists? And there seems to be more than one question here.

Comment: I guess what you see in a `dict` is like `{"key" : "value"}`, so it's a pair of key & value but (most likely) not 2 variables.

Comment: You can also have dicts of dicts or lists of dicts, tough you may want to use named tuples instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. I'll go from easy to harder.

1. Multi-dimensional arrays

A multi-dimensional array is like an array inside an array, like this:

If we wanted to store pets with their animal type and age

```
    CODE:
    multi-array = [["dog", 8], ["cat", 10]]
    DanielsPet = multi-array[0]
    print(DanielsPet[1])

    RESULT:
    8
```

Now although this works you have to try and remember a numerical value for everything (you could of course have 'age = 1' and sub that into DanielsPet[age])

2. Multiple instances of classes

Now it sounds like you haven't looked into classes very much so I am going to be brief with this one, let me know if you want more information.

Steps:

1. create the class
2. put instances of that class in a list
3. read / edit the instances

   ```
   #basic class
   class basic: 
       def __init__(self, x, y):
           self.x = x
           self.y = y

   list = [basic(5, 10), basic(10, 20)]
   print (list[0].x, list[1].y)
   list[0].x = 15
   print (list[0].x, list[1].y)

   RESULT:
   (5, 20)
   (15, 20)
   ```

Here we are able to store 'instances' of a class which all contain their own variables, these can easily be changed and reprinted (list[0].x = 15)

Let me know if you need anymore help or want a more specific example.